# jQuery When I select an Option to call a function

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

When I select one result from my DB, I want to call a function that fills the field "Linha" with the respective info, like the picture below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdXSX.png]

Here is my code:

My autocomplete:

```
$("#produto").autocomplete({
    source: '/pedidoOnline/index.php/Pedidos/search',
    minLength: 2,
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        $("#produto").val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#procura_produto').val(ui.item.id);
            }
    });
```

The function that I want to call to fill the field "Linha":

```
function preencherLinhaProduto(obj) {
    $("#buscaLinha").autocomplete({
        source: '/pedidoOnline/index.php/Pedidos/pesquisarLinhaProduto/' + $('#procura_produto').val(),
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $(obj).each(function() {
                $(this).closest('tr').find('input.cod_linha').val(ui.item.id);
                $(this).closest('tr').find('input.linha').val(ui.item.value);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Produtos" class="btn btn-success" onClick="dialogProcurarProdutos()">
    <div id="dialogProdutos" title="Procurar produtos cadastrados">
        <label for="produto">Informe o produto que deseja procurar</label>
        <input required type="hidden" name="procura_produto" id="procura_produto"/>
        <input required class="inputGG form-control" type="text" name="produto" id="produto" placeholder="Digite no mÃ­nimo as duas letras iniciais"/>"
    </div>
```

And the search of field "Linha"

```
public function pesquisarLinhaProduto() {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->loadModel('ProcuraProdutoPedOnline');
    // Consultando pelo que o usuÃ¡rio estÃ¡ digitando
    $produto = $this->request->params['pass'][0];
    $linhas = $this->ProcuraProdutoPedOnline->find('all', array(
            'fields' => array('cd_linha', 'ds_linha'),
            'conditions' => array(
                    'cd_cpl_tamanho' => "$produto",
            )
    ));

    // Formatar resultado
    $result = array();
    foreach ($linhas as $key => $linha) {
        $result[$key]['id'] = (int) $linha['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['cd_linha'];
        $result[$key]['label'] = utf8_encode($linha['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_linha']);
    }

    $linhas = $result;

    echo json_encode($linhas);
}
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML as well?

Comment: can you log in your select function the ui value. console.log(ui)

Comment: where do you call `function preencherLinhaProduto(obj)`? Should it go in the `select: function(event, ui)` of `$("#produto").autocomplete({...})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are almost there!
you need to call the callback function (which in this case looks to be  preencherLinhaProduto) from inside the 'select' callback of autocomplete.
[tiny jsfiddle for this scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/xngLuczn/ is here]

```
select: function (event, ui) {
        console.log(ui.item); //just to check
        preencherLinhaProduto(ui.item.value); //send the value here as parameter 
                                              //so the function can be generic
    }
```

Incase you are getting errors inspite of doing so, please post relevant error logs for a more helpful answer.

Also i would suggest you make the select callback and the actual autocomplete potion separate (without using anonymous functions) so as to keep it genric, clean and easy for yourself to understand and enhance as required.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It worked !... Now I haver another problem... my query in DB works fine, brings me the result that I want, but in my function, comes just []... Seeing the Firebug in Mozilla Firefox " Answer : [] ".    Thanks again.

Comment: Check your JSFiddle link, currently is it broken.

Comment: @TimLewis thanks for pointing it out. the closing bracket got in the way. updated.

Comment: @EdsonRodrigues glad i could help. 
if your query is working as expected, then i would assume there is something with the technique of how you are returning your server side data to the client side that is giving you the issue. 
Also feel free to show your appreciation by accepting the answer.

Comment: @suvartheec, my Query in DB is working, but code debugging in firefox, comes an Array [] empty rs.. I'm using json_encode() to return.

Comment: @EdsonRodrigues when you say "_but code debugging in firefox_" it means the response is already there in the client side. i was pointing to the step before that, i.e. are you sure your server side logic is sending back the exact thing that you want/expect?
one way to ensure that using the "network" tab to see the ajax response.
also, make sure you are debugging the variable _after_ it has been assigned the value, not _before_ it. (i know its a very small thing and you might have already done that, but just to ensure..)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @suvartheec :

> select: function (event, ui) {
>           console.log(ui.item); //just to check
>           preencherLinhaProduto(ui.item.value); //send the value here as parameter 
>                                                 //so the function can be generic
>       }

It worked, thanks a lot.